# Is a downvote troll targeting me?

Tags: discussion, support

I have noticed a pattern where exactly one day after I post an answer in the Ubuntu section, my answer receives exactly one downvote. It seems plausible that if it is always the same person downvoting me, that this person is using downvotes for a vendetta. Is it possible to find out if all the downvotes are coming from the same user? I don't care about the downvotes, I just want to know if there is somebody who hates me and why.

Comment: That is a suspicion that can only be checked by a moderator, I assume. Why don't you just come to the chat ([AU General Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)) and ping one of our mods, like Oli or Seth.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu also does downvote pattern checks, so if there is a pattern of someone downvoting you maliciously the system has measures to detect and reverse this.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi, I don't think the system is smart enough to detect "spaced-out" downvotes. It only detects a seriers of downvotes in a short amount of time.

Comment: Sorry I have seen this post pop up a few times and it reminded me of a joke: you have to be careful of the difference between trolls and internet trolls... one sort is slow-witted, ugly and bad-tempered, the other is imaginary :)

Comment: As of today you have no downvotes at all, in fact on 5 posts you are +18, I think you have a cognitive bias ie, you notice the bad but not the good, I understand it is annoying but if you compare your up votes to down you can clearly see alot more ups.

Answer (score 23):

You've posted 5 answers. 3 have received 1 downvote. That's not all your answers. It also isn't enough data to bring anything to light.

Seeing this the best I can suggest is, for now, ignoring the downvotes. Just make sure that your answers actually answer the question and fulfil the [How do I write good answers?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) section of the help center and you should be golden.

You're going to get random downvotes at times and as long as you are certain your posts are definitely *answers* to the question, and good quality ones, there isn't much you can do. If this pattern persists a few more times drop me a note [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) by including `@Seth` in your message and I will re-check the tooling.

Answer (score 1):

I just got down-voted and Id like to add that I re-read my post and it had bad wording, and i fixed it, and my down vote disappeared and my answer got up voted, so that's good, but please (downvoter) comment on why down voting posts....

Answer (score -1):

Down votes on a site like this are not implemented well IMHO, a down vote can be that someone doesn't like your answer in pole position because they think that their answer is better.

You also have and I have noted this myself, a problem with post snobbery and if someone doesn't like the way you ask a question, you find that these grammar natzi's jump in and you get hit. Been there myself with a different user account, got no help whatsoever and with this user account too, got down voted because some people didn't like my questions...

Sorry but it is not a "Question" if that person likes your question or not, it is a question of if that person down voting your post actually fully comprehends the issue, something I am finding is a major problem, people and comprehending a situation at hand.

I think it is prudent to insert a stop that will stop people down voting a question by a poster UNTIL they themselves have either posted an answer or a comment and also a flag to show that this person voted.

Only real option if that is not going to be implemented is to remove the down vote option altogether, something I figure is why Facebook do not have a dislike button because of all the problems it introduces.

Simply put, if you don't like an answer, why should someone be allowed to down vote and just because that person does not like the question, FFS.

Another issue surrounds the answer, just because an answer is voted as top answer does not by any means, mean that it is correct or appropriate. If anything, the Person asking for help should be the person to up vote the answer they chose that works for them and no amount of down vote or up votes should detract from that chosen answer.

Comment: Seems like you posted a question of your own... If it was, we'd need to see examples to get the picture. In general: dangerous, useless or otherwise bad answers do exist. Good to use downvotes on to make that clear. Also good the OP of a question is not the only one to judge the quality of an answer. You are forgetting this is not a help desk; what we do here is to create a valuable database with Questions & Answers.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm - I hope that you are not referring to me when you say 
"Seems like you posted a question of your own... If it was, we'd need to see examples to get the picture. In general: dangerous, useless or otherwise bad answers do exist. Good to use downvotes on to make that clear. Also good the OP of a question is not the only one to judge the quality of an answer. You are forgetting this is not a help desk; what we do here is to create a valuable database with Questions & Answers. " as I hardly vote on anything here because the voting system is chronic and needs improvement.

Comment: I love how he got downvoted :P, I know this comment isn't helpfull, but I had a laugh! PS: I just got here for same reason, random downvote made no sense.... life goes on.